# Eclipse plugin / RCP : Showing menu via handler

Tags: java, eclipse, rcp, plugin.xml

I'm looking to create a toolbar with a drop-down menu largely identical to Eclipse's "Open Console" button in the console view.

I can do this by programmatically adding actions (which is what the Console View does), however I'm looking to do this via commands & handlers in plugin.xml.

The instructions at https://wiki.eclipse.org/Menu_Contributions/Dropdown_Command are *extremely* good, however I'm looking to show the drop-down menu when the button itself is clicked (I.E.: clicking the button behaves the same as clicking the drop-down menu triangle to the right of the button). Again: identical to how the "Open Console" button works.

However I've no clue how to do this in "plugin.xml land". I've tried the following in the handler:

```
@Override
public Object execute(ExecutionEvent event) throws ExecutionException {
    Event e = (Event) event.getTrigger();
    ToolBar t = ((ToolItem) e.widget).getParent();
    Menu m = t.getMenu();
    m.setVisible(true);
[...]
```

... however `t.getMenu()` returns a null ...

Comment: Note: Eclipse itself nearly always uses the extension point method. This isolates you from any changes to how menus are done internal (like the major changes that happened from Eclipse 3 to Eclipse 4).

Comment: I will get there eventually. It's a shame that the examples I can find in the shipping product that do what I want to seem to make use of actions, but there's gotta be a way to get a handle on the defined menu via extension points :-)